# Initializing variable in a private function when inheriting from NSObject

Tags: ios, swift

When I try to initialize a variable in a private function while extending `NSObject`:

```
class MyClass: NSObject {

    private var _myVar: Int

    override init() {
        initializeMyVar()
        super.init()
    }

    private func initializeMyVar() {
        _myVar = 4
    }
}
```

I get

> 'self' used in method call 'initializeMyVar' before 'super.init' call

If I try to call `initializeMyVar()` before `super.init()`, but switch the lines so that `super.init()` is called first:

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    initializeMyVar()
}
```

I get

> Property 'self._myVar' not initialized at super.init call

The only way to get rid of the errors is to get rid of the private function and initialize the variable first.

```
override init() {
    _myVar = 4
    super.init()
}
```

Why is this? Is it not possible to initialize non-optional member variables in a private function when extending `NSObject`?

Comment: I would strongly suggest not to use underscores in variable names, especially variable names beginning with underscore in Swift.

Comment: @DominikBucher Really? I thought that was convention for private fields.

Comment: Marking the variable private is enough I think. Really I cannot think of other reason than historical C habits to use the underscore in there. I have seen some people naming stored property `_someVar` and computed property `someVar` or vica versa - this smells really bad code and that you are very likely doing something really wrong... `_` has special meaning in function parameters and empty unused parameters. (which could possibly confuse someone) I would say it's like naming variables with emojis. It's not technically bad.. It's just bullshit :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
initializeMyVar()
super.init()
```

It has no connection with `NSObject`. It's general rule when you're calling `init` of superclass; you can't call method of `self` before you initialize your object or before you assign all `non-optional` variables

```
_myVar = 4
super.init()
```

---

```
super.init()
initializeMyVar()
```

In second case where you assign variable after `super.init()`, you don't give value to your variable and this isn't possible because then your value would have `nil` which also isn't possible because your variable isn't optional. Then in this case make your variable optional

```
private var _myVar: Int?
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to use your own private initializer is by marking the variable as `non-optional` explicitly. Like the following code:

```
class MyClass: NSObject {

    private var _myVar: Int!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        initializeMyVar()
    }

    private func initializeMyVar() {
        _myVar = 4
    }
}
```